# Empty Path variable on Mac?

Tags: bash, file, directory, path

In Terminal, I entered the command `echo $Path` and it printed out an empty line. I don't think the Path variable is empty, though, because when I enter `nano ~/.bash_profile` I see the following:

```
[[ -s "$HOME/.profile" ]] && source "$HOME/.profile" # Load the default .profile

[[ -s "$HOME/.rvm/scripts/rvm" ]] && source "$HOME/.rvm/scripts/rvm" # Load RVM into a shell session *as a function*
```

(The second line is from an unsuccessful attempt to install the non-system version of Ruby.)

Comment: I don't know about MacOS but in other linux/unix environments variable names are case sensitive; instead of `$Path` try `$PATH` (ALL CAPS)

Comment: It's the same on macOS, which is POSIX-compliant.

Answer (score 1):

Resolved; I should have made PATH all uppercase.